# Orange Bar in Final Cut Pro X 10.0.6

Tags: final-cut-pro

Before whenever I imported videos on my timeline, there would be an orange bar in my event browser indicating I've used that portion of the clip. In the new 10.0.6 version, I don't see this. Is there some kind of setting I have to turn on, or was I imagining it this whole time and this never existed?

Answer (score 1):

FCP X is a complete re-write of the software, many and most features that everyday professional editors use when video editing are no longer available in FCP X, this feature was not included.

Update:

Also this only works on true Time-based cameras, a 5D or 7D will not produce this feature even in FCP 7